# Module name matching

Tags: raku

I have a list of module names, as `Str`s, extracted from the `META6.json`. Specifically, the `depends` array. This contains the following entries:

```
"Config::Parser::toml:ver<1.0.1+>",                                   
"Config:api<1>:ver<1.3.5+>",                                      
"Dist::Helper:ver<0.21.0+>",                                      
"Hash::Merge",                                                  
"Terminal::Getpass:ver<0.0.5+>",
```

How can I best match individual entries? Doing `eq` string matches isn't specific enough, as `Config` wouldn't match `Config:api<1>:ver<1.3.5+>` as a string. Trying to match using `.starts-with` also wouldn't work correctly, as `Config:ver<1.3.5>` wouldn't match `Config:api<1>:ver<1.3.5>`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
use Zef::Distribution::DependencySpecification;

my $spec-ver-all     = Zef::Distribution::DependencySpecification.new("Foo::Bar");
my $spec-ver-zero    = Zef::Distribution::DependencySpecification.new("Foo::Bar:ver<0>");
my $spec-ver-one     = Zef::Distribution::DependencySpecification.new("Foo::Bar:ver<1>");
my $spec-ver-oneplus = Zef::Distribution::DependencySpecification.new("Foo::Bar:ver<1+>");
my $spec-ver-two     = Zef::Distribution::DependencySpecification.new("Foo::Bar:ver<2>");
my $spec-ver-three   = Zef::Distribution::DependencySpecification.new("Foo::Bar:ver<3>");

say $spec-ver-one.spec-matcher($spec-ver-all);         # True
say $spec-ver-one.spec-matcher($spec-ver-two);         # False
say $spec-ver-zero.spec-matcher($spec-ver-oneplus);    # False
say $spec-ver-oneplus.spec-matcher($spec-ver-oneplus); # True
say $spec-ver-three.spec-matcher($spec-ver-oneplus);   # True
```